# Is there something like WMI for Linux?

Tags: linux, wmi

I like the whole WMI concept, and I could really make use of it under Linux (in some scripts). Is there something like that for Linux systems?

Comment: Hi Geo, where the posted answers helpful? Can you provide more information for the OS you are interested and which solution you used? - if you used any. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andreas, in the end I gave up on the WMI idea, and I just used the info made available in the files.

Comment: I know this is older than dirt but in case anyone stumbles upon it, a lot of work has been done on OpenLMI and so anyone interested in this should check it out. WMI is Microsoft's CIM implementation product whereas OpenLMI is the GNU/Linux CIM offering (chiefly developed by Red Hat for the time being).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not really.  Are you using WMI to get system parameters, or to query processes, or to change configuration, or monitor for system events, or what?

The kernel exposes a lot of information and tunable knobs via the `/proc` and `/sys` filesystems.  No query language, just a organized hierarchy of directories and files.  Some of these files are read-only, read-write, or write-only; some of them are `poll`able.

Some services may have custom clients to query and update configuration on the fly -- [chrony](http://chrony.sunsite.dk/)'s `chronyc` comes to mind, but even the very most basic `init` has `initctl`.  Newer services like [HAL](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) can be introspected and manipulated over [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).

Comment: You can do that on windows too, via the WinAPI kernel API, like on Linux you have the Linux API that can be accessed via /proc and /sys, but a system like WMI makes managing processes easier, from what it seems, no need to deal with nasty API calls.

Answer (score 33):

Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is Microsoft's implementation of the [WBEM](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/wbem) (Web Based Enterprise Management) standard from the [Distributed Management Task Force](http://www.dmtf.org/home). These standards are available and used in several flavors of *nix systems. Just as an example, here is a [SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sblim) that enables WBEM on Linux systems. There is a standard called CIM (Common Information Model) which is described by the DTMF as follows:

> CIM provides a common definition of
>   management information for systems,
>   networks, applications and services,
>   and allows for vendor extensions.
>   CIM's common definitions enable
>   vendors to exchange semantically rich
>   management information between systems
>   throughout the network.

Comment: Microsoft has open-sourced [OMI](http://www.opengroup.org/software/omi), an implementation of WBEM for Linux/UNIX, and is what is used by SCCM 2012 to query Linux systems.

Comment: Current OMI link: https://github.com/microsoft/omi

Answer (score 8):

[OpenLMI](http://www.openlmi.org/) seems to be designed for exactly that purpose... It provides instrumentation to monitor and control Linux-based servers.

There is also [WBEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management) agents for GNU/Linux (like [OpenPegasus](http://www.openpegasus.org)).

It actually seems that OpenLMI uses Pegasus as the external interface.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ, but YES, there is.
Get FWTS and run

```
fwts wmi -
```

And you will see how is it implemented and what is possible to read/modify.

More here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/WMI

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the /proc interfaces.  You can get a lot of system information there.  There are also many excellent utilities for gathering system information.  The sysstat packages are always one of the first things I install these days.

Edit:  You can always query SNMP as well.  There is a lot of information exposed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be helpful for you. Have a look at this post: http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux