# Get the operating system of a remote server with C# (non WMI solution)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, unix

I am building a server information tool in ASP.NET.
I have the access to the remote servers (username, password, server name).

I **`need to get the OS and version of OS`** running on each of the servers (Windows or **Unix/Linux**)

I have tried searching for a solution and in most of the places, people talk about `WMI`.
But `WMI` wont work if it is a Linux/Unix machine, i suppose.

**Is there a way with which we can achieve this with C#?**

Comment: you need to check if the server publishes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS. if it doesnt, you have no way of knowing without logging into the server

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I have the credentials with me. If its a `unix/linux` machine, how does the logging in work from `C#`

Comment: you would need a way of logging in to the server via ssh through C# and then run something like `cat /proc/version` or `uname -a` through that tunnel and parsing the result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/932217/74015